# Unwrap phase angles in a vector by adding multiples of ±2π

Tags: signals, modelica, unwrap

I am working with Modelica and I am looking for a function to "Unwrap"phase angles in a vector by adding multiples of ±2π.
Can anybody have an idea or a hint to do a such algorithm under Modelica?

I understand Matlab-like implementation of it:

```
%Unwrap the signal xw(n) 
xu = xw; 
for i=2:length(xw) 
difference = xw(i)-xw(i-1); 
if difference > pi 
xu(i:end) = xu(i:end) - 2*pi; 
elseif difference < -pi 
xu(i:end) = xu(i:end) + 2*pi; 
end
```

I would preferably to do it "continually" continuous domain but not on a sampled signal batch as code snippet ...

If you have idea on Modelica implementation I would very appreciate it.

Thank you.
Peter

Comment: Simply type `edit unwrap` in MATLAB to get the source code of the built-in. Then translate it to your language.

Comment: How are you planning to use the function?

Comment: I want to further use in integration by "der()" function

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the usage. 
Maybe it helps to have a look at function Modelica.Math.atan3 
Othwerwise pease describe your use case. 
HTH Toni

Comment: I have algorithm returning individual components (alpha,beta) then I need to have a frequency of this rotating vector. I am doing it by integration.   
vector_angle = atan2(vector_beta, vector_alpha);
der(vector_freq) = vector_angle;